# WalletConnect on iOS redirects to the MetaMask AppStore instead of opening the Metamask application

Tags: ios, app-store, deep-linking, metamask, wallet-connect

I am currently using the WalletConnect Standalone Client within my web application to perform a message signature with the Metamask application.

I implement the signature method as indicated on the [documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/1.0/quick-start/dapps/client#sign-personal-message-personal_sign).

```
const message = "Hello World";

const msgParams = [
  convertUtf8ToHex(message), 
  "0xac11ea55101f03ea7a94c1379bc3ab32e65e62d3"];

connector
  .signPersonalMessage(msgParams)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

However, when I select Metamask from the WalletConnect modal, I am redirected to the AppStore on the Metamask page even though the application is installed (last version dated January 25, 2023).

When I click on the "Open" button from the AppStore I can access Metamask and I can make the signature. But after validation of the signature I am not redirected to my application but I am redirected again to the AppStore on the page of Metamask. Note that this behavior is not present on Android

I saw that a [discussion](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/pull/4167) on the Metamask git repository was opened about this and that it is notably about deep links.

Is there a way to fix this redirection problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.